# If I daven amida very slowly what do I do when the shatz reaches Kedusha?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, tzibur-community, kedusha-prayer

I strive to synchronize my tefila with the tzibur on Shema and the beginning of Shmoneh Esra.

However, I daven quite slowly (metoch nesyon kavana)  and I am almost always somewhere in the middle when the shatz is hitting kedusha.

This seems problematic to me.   I have not been able to find specific reference to slow daveners in the Mishna Brura.

I am aware of the halacha that if you join Shmoneh Esra late - you say the berachot be'kol together with the shatz.

This is a different case - where one starts with the kahal and falls behind and must remain silent.

Comment: "and must remain silent": sounds like you know the answer already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 104:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=) & [Aruch Hahulchan 104:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=182&hilite=) say that one who is in middle of Shemona Esrei when the Chazan reaches Kedusha should remain quiet and listen to the Chazan recite the Kedusha and it is as if he responded.

Comment: But you're not allowed to interrupt the Amidah, and if you accept the principle of "shome'a ke-oneh", then it is as if you spoke the responses and you would be interrupting.

Comment: @paquda, this _halacha_ (listening to _k'dusha_ during one's own _sh'mone esre_) is cited IIRC as proof to one possibility in a [_chakira_](/a/8736) about how _shomea k'one_ works. Alas, I'm not sure I recall what exactly the two possibilities are, and don't want to risk misstating them.

Comment: @paquda: Biur halacha asks your question and says that even though it is an interruption, that is how we rule one should remain quiet and listen. See also further in the Aruch Hashulchan where he also asks your question and says that this is how we do it.

Comment: This was my original concern, i.e. that stopping and listening as an interruption.
@GershonGold - thank you for bringing this down.  What is the siman / seif of that Biur Halacha? 

Thanks everyone!